# How to allow AWS user to see but not launch, start or stop instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have set a policy for an AWS user as such:

```js
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
         "Resource":"*"
      }
   ]
}
```

The intent was to allow a user with this policy to **view** EC2 instances on the console, but not to actually **do** anything with them. The problem is, once this policy is applied, the user can start, stop, terminate and launch new instances even though none of those permissions are addressed in the above policy, AFAIK.

Why is this happening with the above policy, and what can I do to prevent it (i.e. achieve the "view but not touch" result I'm after)?

Comment: OK - never mind [insert emoticon for embarrassment here]. As Steffen guessed, I had an errant "ec2:*" permission (i.e. "go ahead, do whatever you want") attached elsewhere.

Comment: sir i want to apply this policy to a single instance. is that possible? if yes how? I am stuck a lot in this. i want to restrict a single user to a single instance

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Due to limitations in the comment editor, I'm going to post a new "answer" below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Amazon IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) policies are *Deny by default*, which is not identical to *Explicit Deny*, see [The Difference Between Denying by Default and Explicit Deny](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_EvaluationLogic.html#AccessPolicyLanguage_Interplay) for details.

Accordingly, the observed behavior wouldn't be possible by default, so there must be another policy in place for this user explicitly granting the undesired actions like `ec2:RunInstances`. You have the following options to remedy this:

#### Identify/Remove Explicit Allow

You can analyze which policy grants the undesired actions by means of the excellent new [AWS Identity and Access Management Policy Simulator](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/10/aws-identity-and-access-management-policy-simulator.html), which is utterly helpful for issues like this.

#### Add Explicit Deny

You can add an explicit deny for those actions the user shouldn't be able to perform , e.g.:

```js
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RebootInstances",
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note that the latter would still allow quite some other EC2 actions that you might not want, so a more complete approach to explicitly deny all but the desired ones would be to facilitate the [NotAction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#NotAction):

> The NotAction element lets you specify an exception to a list of actions. For example, you can use NotAction to let users use only the Amazon SQS SendMessage action, without having to list all the actions that the user is not allowed to perform. Using NotAction can sometimes result in shorter policies than using an Action element and listing many actions.

- **Warning:** Please be aware that it is easy to restrict more than you intend and even lock yourself out when using `NotAction` for an explicit `Deny` - always make sure the `Resource` statement is only targeting the desired resources. For example, simply using the common wildcard `*` instead of a more specific resource selector like `arn:aws:ec2:*:*:*` boils down to 'deny all but these actions *for every service*' - for the example at hand this would include the ability to delete the erroneous policy again! This is best avoided by carefully simulating the policy upfront.

A resp. policy might look like this:

```js
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "NotAction": [
        "ec2:Describe*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You were right. As I'm about to add to my own question, there was an errant "ec2:*" set somewhere else I didn't notice. Drove me batty for a while.

Comment: Also, note that I'm very leery of using explicit denies pretty much anywhere, since they take precedence. If I have to, I'll add them as low down on the food chain (i.e. as specific to the user or users I want to deny) as I can get away with.

Answer (score 0):

For user3086014, create a policy similar to the one below:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action": [
             "ec2:DescribeInstances",
             "ec2:StartInstances",
             "ec2:StopInstances",
             "ec2:RebootInstances"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:0123456789012:instance/i-ffffffff"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Change the actions to the ones you want to allow your user to perform. Change the resource to identify *your* instance - i.e. change the account ID (I've written 0123456789012 above) and the instance ID (I've written i-ffffffff above). Then apply that policy to your user. If you want to allow use of two instances, add a second ARN with a comma-delimiter between the ARNs (as is required JSON form).

Please next time make a separate question. It's awkward having questions-answers in the comments themselves. Thanks!

Comment: sir when i m doing this with console its not working im getting this error : `You are not authorized to describe Running Instances
You are not authorized to describe Elastic IPs 
You are not authorized to describe Volumes 
You are not authorized to describe Snapshots `

Comment: The quickest thing to do is replace "DescribeInstances" in the above example with "Describe*". However, there is no substitute for studying the list of actions to determine what you CAN control - and then drawing up a plan of what you WANT to control. For EC2 actions, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html - you can click on "Actions" or "List of Actions By Function", which is better organized. Within either list, you can click on a specific action to learn more about it. This documentation is more for API programming, but the names map to IAM permissions.

Comment: @JackLThornton - unfortunately this won't work currently, because `Describe*` actions are not yet enabled for resource level permissions (i.e. a specific instance id here), rather only work with the wildcard resource `*` (see my resp. answer and subsequent comments to user3086014's question [How can I allow a single user to have access of an ec2 instance in AWs console using IAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21700365/45773) for the background, where I've already explained this in great detail to no avail ...).

Comment: Hmmm.. you're correct, I had forgotten about that. However, you can move the "Describe*" to a separate statement to allow a user to *see* everything; although they can see everything, they're still only allowed to manipulate items as per the resource-limited statement. The only caveat is that AWS web console does not check for permissions before putting up UI, only when running the action - so it will appear that AWS is about to allow a user to do something prohibited, and will only tell them to go pound sand after they've hit the "apply" or "execute" button on the action.