# How can I allow a single user to have access of an ec2 instance in AWs console using IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am exploring IAM. I want to give access to a single ec2 instance to a user. I have created a policy for this as:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1392113879000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:instance/instance_id"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am getting this error:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the error]

I have referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548062/aws-iam-access-management)

Any lead is appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Resource-Level Permissions for EC2 and RDS Resources](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/07/resource-permissions-for-ec2-and-rds-resources.html) you are referring to are not yet available for all API actions, but AWS in gradually adding more, see this note from [Amazon Resource Names for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#EC2_ARN_Format):

> **Important** Currently, not all API actions support individual ARNs; we'll add support for additional API actions and ARNs for additional
>   Amazon EC2 resources later. For information about which ARNs you can
>   use with which Amazon EC2 API actions, as well as supported condition
>   keys for each ARN, see [Supported Resources and Conditions for Amazon
>   EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources).

You will find that all `ec2:Describe*` actions are indeed absent still from [Supported Resources and Conditions for Amazon EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources) at the time of this writing, and these are the ones required for listing resources e.g. in the AWS Management Console and triggering the errors you are seeing in turn (*"You are not authorized to **describe** ..."*).

See also [Granting IAM Users Required Permissions for Amazon EC2 Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html) for a concise summary of the above and details on *the ARNs and Amazon EC2 condition keys that you can use in an IAM policy statement to grant users permission to create or modify particular Amazon EC2 resources* - this page also mentions that AWS will *add support for additional actions, ARNs, and condition keys in 2014*.

Comment: but i cant see the instances in the console

Comment: i have given "test" user access to a single instance but when i log on to the console I coudnt see any instance

Comment: Sure, that's because you are applying `Allow` to the explicit resource `arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:instance/instance_id` (a 'resource level permission'), and this doesn't work for `ec2:Describe*` actions yet as outlined above - put another way, for the time being your `Allow`statement only applies to e.g. `ec2:StartInstances` and all other actions listed in [Supported Resources and Conditions for Amazon EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources), where `ec2:Describe*` actions are missing still.

Comment: It means i should remove `describe` action from the action list

Comment: No, you cannot fix this the way you desire right now, sorry - in order to 'see' this one instance, you'd need to `Allow` access to all instances  by means of the wildcard resource (`*`), which is what you do not want.

Comment: even if i have removed the describe actions still i cant see the instance. then whats the use of this, I cant restrict the user access to a single instance.

Comment: It means this is not possible right now. :( Can u suggest some more use cases for IAM. I have to explore IAM.

Comment: As I said, AWS is gradually rolling out this resource level permission feature - it is already useful as is, because there are many scenarios, where you do not need to 'see' the instance via `Describe*`, rather starting/stopping etc is entirely sufficient (for example many automation scenarios) - unfortunately this doesn't apply to using the AWS Management Console, i.e. your apparent use case.

Comment: Can i restrict a user from performing the  root level operations on an instance and he can only execute few commands that wont hamper the configuration of the instance ? Is it possible?

Comment: @user3086014 - unaccepting my answer for no obvious reason other than apparently being unsatisfied with me not answering again right away (you know, some people aren't online/available for free advise 24/7) is not exactly encouraging me to try and help you any further, after all, I've correctly answered your initial question and you acknowledged this already. You should generally ask new questions separately, in case they come up during a conversation like this. That being said, ...

Comment: ... IAM permissions for your AWS account have nothing to do with on instance permissions for your Operating System at all - your question _seems_ to suggest you are not really familiar with Unix/Linux usage and administration, which is a dangerous place to be for running systems in the public cloud; before continuing your EC2 experiments, I highly recommend to educate yourself with resp. learning material and/or seek advise from experienced Unix/Linux users/administrators accordingly (can't help you with this, sorry). Good luck!

Comment: Sir, with due respect i have unaccepted the answer because i was not convinced. they have shown in the same link check example no 3 on the link that u have referred. Its written over there that you can stop or start particular instance. They why cant i implement the same.

Comment: sir still im not convinced the doc says that it is possible but i cant see anything on the console!!!